# Create print-friendly applications while using client-side templating

Tags: javascript, css, printing, client-side, single-page-application

It looks like chrome & safari do not consider client-side templates when they go to print. Is there any work-around for this?

Basically, the print page looks as if no templating has been done.

Any leads would be great, thanks!

Matt

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you using a templating library?

Comment: What kind of "client-side templates" are you talking about?

Comment: well specifically I'm using mustache, but this is a more general question. I'm passing JSON from the server, in the form of `window.user = {...}`